# Form upload in Node.js + Express (via multiparty)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

this is my upload method in app/routes/index.js:

```
exports.uploadFile = function(req, res) {
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var gm = require('gm');
var fs = require('fs');
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var size = '';
var fileName = '';
form.on('part', function(part){
    if(!part.filename) return;
    size = part.byteCount;
    fileName = part.filename;
});
form.on('file', function(name,file){
    console.log(file.path);
    console.log(__dirname);
    console.log('filename: ' + fileName);
    console.log('fileSize: '+ (size / 1024));
    var tmp_path = file.path
    var target_path = __dirname + '/uploads/fullsize/' + fileName;
    var thumbPath = __dirname + '/uploads/thumbs/';
    fs.renameSync(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if(err) console.error(err.stack);
    });
    res.redirect('/uploads/fullsize/' + fileName);
        console.log(target_path);
    /*gm(tmp_path)
        .resize(150, 150)
        .noProfile()
        .write(thumbPath + 'small.png', function(err) {
            if(err) console.error(err.stack);       
        });*/
});
form.parse(req);
```

};

I call this method from app.js as

```
app.post('/uploadFile', routes.uploadFile);
```

when I upload file from upload form, a get this error message in console:

```
/tmp/9039-1m6kw46.jpg
/home/danyaloff/Development/nodejs/projects/nodetest1/routes
filename: 3D-Background-Wallpapers-HD-Wallpapers-in-HD.jpg
fileSize: 910.255859375

fs.js:543
   return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath),
             ^
   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/9039-1m6kw46.jpg'
   at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:543:18)
   at Form.<anonymous> (/home/danyaloff/Development/nodejs/projects/nodetest1/routes/index.js:25:6)
at Form.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/danyaloff/Development/nodejs/projects/nodetest1/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:527:10)
at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at fs.js:1596:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
23 Dec 03:52:59 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

but when I use upload function in my app.js file as:

```
app.post('/uploadFile', function(req, res){
    //my upload function
});
```

everything works perfect. what is the problem in my code? thx!

Comment: I was using your code snippet. However I ran into an issue where the form.on 'part' was not raised. Consequently the filename and filesize are empty. Can you help fix it for me?

Answer (score 7):

the problem is solved after using:

```
var target_path = './uploads/fullsize/' + fileName;
```

instead of

```
var target_path = __dirname + '/uploads/fullsize/' + fileName;
```